# Spring Boot Batch: Need to get JobExecutionContext into ItemWriteListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

My goal is to get the JobExecutionContext into an ItemWriterListener. I've tried a few different approaches to getting this wired without success.This is the snippet from most recent version. I want to get a JobExecutionContext so I can get the parameters and update them as the job progresses.I think I could get these values after the whole process has completed, but then it would be too late.

```
@Configuration
public class SoftLayerJobConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "softlayerUploadFile",destroyMethod = "")
    public Step softlayerUploadFile(ItemStreamReader<SoftLayerData> softlayerFileReader,
            CompositeItemProcessor<SoftLayerData, SoftLayerData> compositeSoftlayerProcessor,
            CompositeItemWriter<SoftLayerData> compositeSoftlayerDataWriter,
            StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            SoftLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener softLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener,
            SoftLayerDataCounterItemReadListener softLayerDataCounterItemReadListener,
            StepExecutionListener uploadFileExecutionListener,
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("softlayerUploadFile")
                .listener(uploadFileExecutionListener)
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .<SoftLayerData, SoftLayerData>chunk(100)
                .reader(softlayerFileReader)
                .listener(softLayerDataCounterItemReadListener)
                .processor(compositeSoftlayerProcessor)
                .writer(compositeSoftlayerDataWriter)
                .listener(softLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener)
                .build();
    @Autowired
    @Bean(destroyMethod ="") 
    @StepScope
    public SoftLayerDataCounterItemReadListener softLayerDataCounterItemReadListener(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext}") ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        return new SoftLayerDataCounterItemReadListener(jobExecutionContext);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(destroyMethod ="") 
    @JobScope 
    public SoftLayerDataCounterJobExecutionListener softLayerDataCounterJobExecutionListener(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext}") ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        return new SoftLayerDataCounterJobExecutionListener(jobExecutionContext);
    }
    
    @Autowired
    @Bean(destroyMethod ="") 
    @StepScope
    public SoftLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener softLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext}") ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        return new SoftLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener(jobExecutionContext);
    }

    }

}
```

SoftLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener

```
public class SoftLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener implements ItemWriteListener<SoftLayerData>{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SoftLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener.class);

    private AtomicLong runningWriteCount = new AtomicLong(0);

    private ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext;

    public SoftLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener(ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        this.jobExecutionContext = jobExecutionContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeWrite(List<? extends SoftLayerData> items) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterWrite(List<? extends SoftLayerData> items) {
        long runningWriteCount = this.runningWriteCount.addAndGet(items.size());
        logger.info("afterWrite SoftLayerDataCounterItemWriterListener: count="+runningWriteCount);
        
        this.jobExecutionContext.putLong("EXCEL_ITEMS_WRITTEN", runningWriteCount);
        
        long totalRead =this.jobExecutionContext.getLong("EXCEL_ITEMS_READ");
        logger.info("Running percentage processed = "+runningWriteCount/totalRead);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onWriteError(Exception exception, List<? extends SoftLayerData> items) {
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
    ... 125 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Don't... Your writer shhouldn't update the job execution. Use a proper listener (designed for the task) to do that. Also the statistics you are writing are already provided out-of-the-box (and more) so not sure what you think it adds.

Comment: @M.Deinum I made a mistake in the post and corrected it. I meant to get the context in a Listener.  My ultimate goal is to track the current progress. I was going to use the context to report it back to the main instantiator of the job. Where does that happen already?

Comment: Spring Batch already keeps track of the number of items read, processed and written. The total number of chunks etc. It is already kept in the [`StepExecution`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html).

Comment: @M.Deinum I saw it's in the table, but no accessor  methods on StepExecution. Do I have to do a database read to get the latest job status? I suppose I could, just thought there'd be something like stepExecution.getTotalIems

Comment: Check again.. What do you think the `getWriteCount`, `getReadCount` etc. methods do...

Comment: @M.Deinum I used a getWrite for the numerator and stored the denominator (total records) in the itemReader using ExecutionContext. As a favor, can you see my other Q. Re. WebSockets? Thx for your time

Comment: You don't need to store the total records that is the readCount. So it already gets stored, you are just complicating things by adding it again yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I used the getWriteCount on StepExecution and passed the total read from an ItemStreamReader into an ExecutionContext. The latter gives me the known total items as opposed to the total read so far. Please see my related question on WebSockets. Thx for your help